# Return all results within a 30km radius of a specific lat/long point?

Tags: postgis, distance

I have a table with a column `the_geom` which contains data similar to:

```
0103000020E61000000100000005000000CE473AACFA071E40F27FB23340744740336FE841C6231E40873BED903F744740FC150A0ACE231E40D19E2684637647409C9B443D00081E409A9AF82664764740CE473AACFA071E40F27FB23340744740
```

Which when applying the function `ST_AsEWKT(the_geom)` returns:

```
SRID=4326;POLYGON((7.5077921782085 46.9082092877942,7.53493597966353 46.9081898840296,7.53496566473541 46.9249119938446,7.50781341296434 46.9249314035307,7.5077921782085 46.9082092877942))
```

I need to select all data that is within a 30km radius of a specific lat/long point, for example:

- lat = 46.8167
- lng = 6.9333

However whenever I tried to use `ST_Distance()`, I always received values less than 1, and using `ST_DWithin()` always returned true.

Comment: Beautiful answer by Vince: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/how-to-properly-set-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries/247131

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Please Check out the following query for PostgreSQL to get data within certain distance. I hope it will help.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(the_geom, ST_MakePoint(your_lon,your_lat)) <= radius_mi * 1609.34
```

See the documentation for `ST_DistanceSphere` here: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html

Comment: Was able to get it working with:

SELECT * FROM myTable
            WHERE GeometryType(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) = 'POINT'
            AND ST_Distance_Sphere(
                  ST_Point(ST_X(ST_Centroid(the_geom)), ST_Y(ST_Centroid(the_geom))),
                    (ST_MakePoint(6.9333, 46.8167))) <= 18 * 1609.34

Comment: That's great :)

Comment: Just for anyone else wondering, the 1609.34 figure is meters per mile, which is the base unit postgres is using. So to do kilometers, obviously multiply by 1000.

Comment: Pedantic note: it's 1609.344 exactly (by definition)

Comment: Since PostGIS 2.2 the function is called `ST_DistanceSphere`

Answer (score 11):

In my world, using a custom SRID (for Google Maps) something like this worked:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 3785), radius);
```

where the type of `location` is a geometry(Point,3785), and `longitude`, `latitude`, and `radius` are floats (e.g. -100, 44, 30 for 100W/44N/30 "units" -- see below)

See [What is the best way to find all objects within a radius of another object?](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch03.html#id434832) in the postgis docs:

> The `ST_DWithin(geometry, geometry, distance)` function is a handy way of performing an indexed distance search. It works by creating a search rectangle large enough to enclose the distance radius, then performing an exact distance search on the indexed subset of results.

UPDATE: units are not miles for SRID 3785... they seem to be either radians or degrees or something like that. But the specification for my SRID says its units are either meters or degrees and it's definitely neither of those, at least not without some conversion:

`alex=# select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=3785;
 srid | auth_name | auth_srid |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                srtext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                                                         proj4text

 3785 | EPSG      |      3785 | PROJCS["Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator (deprecated)",GEOGCS["Popular Visualisation CRS",DATUM["Popular_Visualisation_Datum",SPHEROID["Popular Visualisation Sphere",6378137,0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7059"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6055"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4055"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3785"],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH]] | +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs`

Comment: What's the difference between 3785 (in your post) and 3857?

Comment: They're different projections. [3875](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acrs%3aEPSG%3a:3875&reportDetail=short&style=urn%3auuid%3areport-style%3adefault-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=EPSG:3875) vs [3857](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acrs%3aEPSG%3a:3857&reportDetail=short&style=urn%3auuid%3areport-style%3adefault-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=EPSG:3857) -- I don't know if one is better than another

Comment: "EPSG 3785 has been deprecated in favor of the otherwise identical EPSG 3857" - https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/pull/61

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you're storing your geometry in a geometry column, not a geography column.
That is fine, but the function [ST_Distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) will return measurements in projection units instead of always meters. In your case (4326), that will be degrees.
Just using a buffer with ST_Within won't work either, as the [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) will measured with degrees too.

You can either convert your data to use geography instead of geometry, or you can convert your point into some projection that uses meters, buffer, then convert back to 4326 to see what is within it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM <your data>
WHERE ST_Within(the_geom, 
                ST_Transform(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(6.9333, 46.8167), 4326), 3857), 30000), 4326)) = 1
```

That projects the point into [3857](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acrs%3aEPSG%3a:3857&reportDetail=short&style=urn%3auuid%3areport-style%3adefault-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=EPSG:3857), which is a projection popular with web maps. Then it buffers it by 30,000 meters then reprojects it back to 4326 before passing it to ST_Within.

Comment: Except a pseudo-Mercator is unreliable for distance, so unless the data is close to the equator, the results will be off, especially with a distance of 30km.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this should work:

```
SELECT gid FROM table 
WHERE ST_DWithin(the_geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(6.9333, 46.8167), 4326), 30000)
```

Comment: if you cast the_geom to geography that should work. st_dwithin(geography(the_geom),geography(<Point, 4326>), 30000)