# ST_DWithin query throwing 42601 error?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, error, query

I am trying to get from a particular point more informations about the surroundings (which are also points). So I wrote this:

```
SELECT *
   FROM osm_point
   WHERE ST_DWithin(way,(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.2385578688105, 51.8435615931295), 4326, 1000);
```

But there is an error

> ERROR: FEHLER:  LINE 3: ...T_MakePoint(12.2385578688105,
>   51.8435615931295), 4326, 1000) ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 133

What is wrong?

Comment: Missing closing paren for ST_SetSRID *and* a missing `::geography` cast after the missing paren. `way` is also missing a geography cast.

Comment: Something like  As wgs84long_lat for SetSRID?

Comment: And the ::geography in connection with my table? like  osm_point.way (way is my geometry)

Comment: If you don't cast both geometry values to geography, ST_DWithin will return all rows within 1000 Cartesian degrees

Comment: In order to leverage a GIST index you need to create one on "Geography(way)". see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/how-to-properly-set-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries/247131#247131

Comment: ohh now i understand nothing anymore ... maybe i have to read a bit more about spatial querys to continue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL error 42601 is a syntax error (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html)). Basically, you had an extra opening parenthesis before `ST_SetSRID` and also a closing missing parenthesis for the same function.

If data type of `osm_point.way` column is `geometry`, one needs to cast it to `geography` in order to [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) evaluate to geodetic distances (instead of planar distances) and in meters (if units of spatial reference aren't already in meters). The same cast to `geography` is valid for `ST_MakePoint` which output is of type `geometry` and the units of applied CRS 4326 is degrees, but you want meters.

So, use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM osm_point
WHERE ST_DWithin(way::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.2385578688105, 51.8435615931295), 4326)::geography, 1000);
```

When using `ST_DWithin` one needs to compare data which have the same SRID. So, if column `osm_point.way` has a different SRID (you [said](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295724/st-dwithin-query-throwing-42601-error/295746?noredirect=1#comment475141_295746) EPSG:3857) from EPSG:4326 (the SRID you used to define the coordinates with `ST_MakePoint`), one needs to transform coordinates first. For that use [ST_Transform](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html). See:

```
SELECT * 
FROM osm_point 
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(way, 4326)::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(12.2385578688105, 51.8435615931295), 4326)::geography, 1000);
```

---

About using indexes to speed up your queries, as suggested by @Vince, take a look  in:

[Setting up indexes for PostGIS distance queries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/how-to-properly-set-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries/247131#247131).