# PostGIS ST_Point_Inside_Circle radius unit

Tags: postgis, postgresql, circle, units

I'm trying to use the ST_Point_Inside_Circle function from PostGIS but I'm not sure about the unit the radius is stored.

Let's say I have a table with the following points:

```
   Id | Point
    1 | POINT(-60.64855 -32.96482) 
    2 | POINT (-60.65871 -32.93411)
```

and I want to query them by doing

```
 st_point_inside_circle(Point,
 -32.93690, -60.64343, radius)
```

Now, I know that distance from (-32.93690, -60.64343) to P1 is of about 1460 m and from (-32.93690, -60.64343) to P2 is of 3117.5 m. 
Using a trial-and-error approach I was able to determine that if 
 radius < 0.02839 and radius > 0.02838 I was able to get the 2 points in my query.
However, the value for radius doesn't make much sense. Which units is it expressed in? Since the distance between points is too short, I don't think that not using a spheroid would affect the results. Maybe I am doing something wrong.
Should I use ST_Buffer instead?

Comment: The units are the units of the geometry, which is degrees. Doing *anything* in Cartesian degrees is a recipe for disaster, so I suggest you test to see if casting your `Point` column to `geography` results in proper meters operation (on a spheroid). See also [this post on  indexes that cover cast geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/how-to-properly-set-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries)