# Return rows where distance is within X meters

Tags: postgis

So how do I write a query to get all rows within X meters of a certain lat/long coordinate?

I tried looking into the docs, but it's super confusing, ideally I just want to write

```
SELECT * 
FROM   locdat
WHERE  ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829),2000, true )
```

but I don't understand anything of the syntax they use in the docs or something like `select ST_MakePoint(loc_point) from locdat` won't work either.

`loc_point` is data like `(54.66965,20.64888)` of type `text`.

Comment: First, you have to make sure your data all has correct spatial reference IDs. For WGS84 data that would be 4326. Second, you need to cast the 4326 `geometry` to `geography` so that `ST_DWithin` uses geodesic distance of 2000 meters, not Cartesian distance of 2000 degrees (or doesn't simply return `false` because the SRIDs are incompatible). Eventually you may have to deal with a [covering index](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/how-to-properly-set-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries) , but only if you have a lot of rows.

Comment: For reference, `SELECT ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.1043, 42.3151),4326)::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(54.6697,20.6489),4326)::geography)` returns `11095628.2` meters (which is larger than 2km)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) takes 2 geometries or geographies.

To use a distance in meters, you can use the geography datatype. You may have to cast your column (and index)

```sql
select * 
from locdat
where ST_DWithin(
        locdat.geog, 
        ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829)::geography,
        2000, 
        true )
```

Comment: Note that his assumes that `locdat.geog` is a `geography` type; otherwise it needs to be cast to  `geography`.

Comment: my lat/long is saved as text type, but im getting an error when i try ```SELECT ST_GeomFromText(locdata.loc_geo, 4326) from locdata```
(ignore the change in table/column names)

Comment: @bas that's a different question. Once you have figured out how to convert your text to a geography, then this answer applies. Please ask a new question with enough details if you need help converting your text to a geog/geom