# Converting a text (lat/lon) to a point or geography

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

In my table I have a column filled with text type lat/lon entries. I want to convert these entries to a point? Or something I can use with PostGIS functions

I am aware of `SELECT ST_PointFromText('POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)', 4326);`, but it does not work when I try to do `SELECT ST_PointFromText('POINT('locdata.loc_geo')', 4326) from locdata`

That just gets me this error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "locdata"
LINE 1: SELECT ST_PointFromText('POINT('locdata.loc_geo')',`.

**Extra info:**
my `locdata.loc_geo` entries are text entries structured like this: `34.032601, 78.551298` (the order doesnt matter, i dont need an exact place, just get the math working)

Comment: Coordinates are entered `X,Y`, so your `loc_geo` values may be backwards.

Comment: The order ***does*** matter since the math will be wrong. {34.032601, 78.551298} is ~400nm north-by-east of Murmansk, while {78.551298, 34.032601} is on the India/China border.

Comment: yeah but its still an existing coordinate on the globe(the main thing was getting the query working at all, the numbers are just something i randomly mashed in)

Comment: If you randomly mash in a far longitude and place it in the latitude spot, your parse will fail. Besides, proper random allocation on the globe would allocate by equal-area, so far-north and far-south values should be less frequent than mid-latitudes -- see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/how-to-properly-set-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries/247131#247131

Comment: well i know that lat has a -90 90 range and long -180 180, so i did keep that in mind. but now that i did get it working, i can work with pre picked existing locations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because stitching two objects (literal string or column) requires a concatenation operator, like `SELECT ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || locdata.loc_geo ||')', 4326) from locdata`

But it won't work either because of the coma and the lat-long swap. Instead, you can read the coordinates, split them in an array, cast it to floats (or double), then construct the point using the coordinates:

```
WITH split_src AS (
  SELECT string_to_array(loc_geo, ', ')::float[]  arr
  FROM locdata)
SELECT st_asText(st_makePoint(arr[2],arr[1])) 
FROM split_src;
```

Comment: ``SELECT ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || locdata.loc_geo ||')', 4326)`` worked(i removed the comma, but what do the ``||`` do in a query?

Comment: As the answer states, `||` is the [string concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-string.html)