# Object in 100 m distance, Error: Operation on mixed SRID geometries

Tags: postgis, point, distance, error

I perform the following query:

`SELECT * FROM "houses" WHERE (ST_Distance(coordinates, 'POINT(-0.374930 39.478400)'::geometry) < 100)`

To find houses around 100 meter distance from: `39.478400, -0.374930`

I'm getting the following error:

**PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries**

What is wrong here?

"Coordinates" is of type: `geometry "coordinates", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"geometry"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point that is created has no SRID, i.e. `0`, which is different than `4326`.

That being said, `st_distance` uses the unit of the CRS, so degrees in this case.

One solution is to use `geography` instead of `geometry`, as the unit is meters, and to use `st_dwithin()` instead of `st_distance` as it makes use of spatial index. Eventually, you will want to add an index on the geography transformation.

```sql
SELECT * FROM "houses" 
WHERE st_dwithin(coordinates::geography, 'POINT(-0.374930 39.478400)'::geography) , 100);
```

Comment: ST_DWithin only takes advantage of the index if a covering index is present. `CREATE INDEX houses_gpx ON houses USING gist(Geography(coordinates))` see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/setting-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries