# Match rows from different tables by comparing similar lat lon coordinates

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, knn

I am new to PostgreSQL and PostGIS. The first project I am working on is the first I am struggeling with and the one I would like to discuss.

I have 2 `stops` tables I call for simplicity **tbl_stops_1** and **tbl_stops_2**

###### tbl_stops_1

```
 feed_index            | integer              |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 stop_id               | text                 |           | not null |         | extended |              | 
 stop_name             | text                 |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 stop_lat              | double precision     |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 stop_lon              | double precision     |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
...
 the_geom              | geometry(Point,4326) |           |          |         | main     |              | 
Indexes:
    "stops_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (feed_index, stop_id)
    "stop_geom_idx" gist (the_geom)
Triggers:
    stop_geom_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON gtfs.stops FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE gtfs.stop_geom_update()
```

Row count:

```
select count(1) from gtfs.stops;
 count  
--------
 523887
```

###### tbl_stops_2

```
feed_index       | integer               |           | not null |                                               | plain    |              | 
 seqno            | bigint                |           | not null | nextval('gtfs.stops_zhv_seqno_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
...
 the_geom         | geometry(Point,4326)  |           |          |                                               | main     |              | 
 SeqNo            | text                  |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
 Type             | text                  |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
 DHID             | text                  |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
 Parent           | text                  |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
 Name             | text                  |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
 Latitude         | text                  |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
 Longitude        | text                  |           |          |                                               | extended |              | 
...
Indexes:
    "stops_zhv_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (feed_index, seqno)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "stops_zhv_feed_index_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (feed_index) REFERENCES gtfs.feed_info(feed_index) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    stop_zhv_geom_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON gtfs.stops_zhv FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE gtfs.stop_zhv_geom_update()
```

Row count:

```
select count(1) from gtfs.stops_zhv;
 count  
--------
 849453
```

Those 2 stops tables are imported into PostgreSQL from different sources. Though they have similarities, they are not the same. In particular `tbl_stops_1` lacks in information in the `tbl_stops_1.stop_name` column. Those rows missing information I like to combine with information from the column `tbl_stops_2.DHID` like this.

```
tbl_stops_1.stop_name = tbl_stops_2.DHID.stringConCat(tbl_stops_1.stop_name);
```

#### How to match those two stops tables?

The values of lat and lon are quite similar in those two stops tables. I can match a stop row from table `tbl_stops_1` with a stop row in table `tbl_stops_2` like this.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_stops_1 JOIN tbl_stops_2 ON ST_DWithin(tbl_stops_1.the_geom, tbl_stops_2.the_geom, ???);
```

#### What am I aiming for?

At the end, I would like to have a view or table where the above string concatenation is done for stops that match because their geographic coordinates are close to each other.

#### Edit no. 1

- I updated the definition to that the stops tables are more alike and * added row counts.
- I like to have a `the_geom` column in both tables to facilitate this project. Anyhow, the function to import the CSV data into the database does not like to do this yet. I'll touch base.

#### Edit no. 2

- I updated the definition to that the stops tables are more alike and * added row counts.
- I updated the matching query using `JOIN`

#### Open Issue

- How make the `JOIN` work and combine it with the string concatenation?

Comment: Those tables are not at all alike, because the second one doesn't have geometry. A `ST_Distance` query cannot use an index, and will therefore be very inefficient. You especially don't want to join to the table without the geometry column, and you want a `JOIN` to do so. Please [Edit] the Question to contain row counts for each table and explain what the query actually does.

Comment: What do you mean with `index` and that the `ST_Distance` query cannot use it? What are `row counts`? I'll asap edit the question. Cheers anyways!

Comment: A row count is the number of features (rows) in a table. Indexes are what make databases worth using.

Comment: @Vince: I am on my way to make both tables more similar to facilitate this project. I know, I am not there yet. Anyhow, do you think I can ```JOIN``` the stops tables already now?

Comment: If you use a ST_DistanceSphere on ST_MakePoint features, PostgreSQL will need to do 406046477655 geodetic comparisons. How long are you willing to wait?  I think you need to spend some more time on geometry table and index construction before you're ready to JOIN.  If you're not using ST_DWithin for the JOIN, you're going to be disappointed. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247113/setting-up-indexes-for-postgis-distance-queries/247131#247131

Comment: @Vince The ```JOIN``` query I am using now takes ages and returns zero rows. I am wondering what is the unit of the distance value in the ST_DWidth() function: meter, degree, aso.? Can you suggest anything for optimization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plain proximity search (e.g. via `ST_DWithin`) comes with the drawback that it finds *all* geometries within the given distance threshold - this may work out in cases where the threshold is in accordance with the overall distribution, but for the given task in general a proximity search is ambiguous.

---

I suspect that the problem definition could in fact be re-phrased into

> "*Find the **single, nearest** stop in `table a` for each stop in `table_b`, and create a new name from its row values.*

This is referred to as (spatial) *(**K**) **N**earest **N**eighbor* search, and can be executed efficiently using a `LATERAL` join in conjunction with the PostGIS implementation of the `<->` distance operator.

There is a decision to make that may have a significant impact: find the closest stop in `table a` for each stop in `table b` - or *vice cersa*. If there is a 1:1 match between stops in both tables, with only tiny differences in their coordinate values, this decision likely has no effect.

The *joined* table (*right hand table* in the join) needs a spatial index for this to be efficient.

For this example I will assume you want to find the closest stop in `tbl_stops_2` to each stop in `tbl_stops_1` (spatial index on `tbl_stops_2` will be used):

```
SELECT
  --t1.<columns>,
  --t2.<columns>,         -- these need to be selected in the LATERAL sub-query
  CONCAT_WS("_", t2."DHID", t1.stop_name) AS stop_name
FROM
  tbl_stops_1 AS t1
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      -- _ts.<columns>,
      "DHID"              -- wrapped in "" if actually uppercase
    FROM
      tbl_stops_2 AS _t2
    ORDER BY
      t1.the_geom <-> _t2.the_geom
    LIMIT
      1
  ) AS t2
;
```

Similarly, you could `UPDATE` your `tbl_stops_1` table:

```
UPDATE
  tbl_stops_1 AS t1
SET
  stop_name = (
    SELECT
      CONCAT_WS("_", t2."DHID", t1.stop_name)
    FROM
      tbl_stops_2 AS t2
    ORDER BY
      t1.the_geom <-> t2.the_geom
    LIMIT
      1
  )
;
```

In both cases, the concatenated `stop_name` will have the structure

```
<t2."DHID">_<t1.stop_name>
```

with `_` being the separator - change this the way you need it.

Comment: I updated about 50 thousand columns from table ```tbl_stops_1``` with about 800 thousand columns from table ```tbl_stops_2``` which took about half a day on a single core virtual machine with about 10 gigabytes of main memory with the processor being the limiting factor. Any ideas how to speed up this update?

Comment: @dancesWithCycles Do you have  a GIST index on `tbl_stops_2`? Don't forget to run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on both tables, just in case but necessarily after creating a missing index.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference and everyone tripping over this issue, I am pasting here my working version based on the above accepted answer.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS :schema.tbl_gtfs_stops_de_not_dhid_refine;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS :schema.tbl_gtfs_stops_de_not_dhid_refine AS SELECT * FROM :schema.tbl_gtfs_stops_de_not_dhid;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS refine_id_idx ON :schema.tbl_gtfs_stops_de_not_dhid_refine(stop_id);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS refine_geom_idx ON :schema.tbl_gtfs_stops_de_not_dhid_refine USING GIST (the_geom);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS zhv_dhid_idx ON gtfs.stops_zhv(dhid);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS zhv_geom_idx ON gtfs.stops_zhv USING GIST (the_geom);
VACUUM ANALYZE;
UPDATE
  :schema.tbl_gtfs_stops_de_not_dhid_refine AS t1
SET
  stop_id = (
    SELECT
      CONCAT_WS(':',t2.dhid, t1.stop_id)
    FROM
      gtfs.stops_zhv AS t2
    ORDER BY
      t1.the_geom <-> t2.the_geom
    LIMIT
      1
  );
```

You can find the code [here](https://git.wtf-eg.de/dancesWithCycles/delfi/src/branch/main/db/sql/refine.sql)